# Angular: OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/authentication/register 0 ()

Tags: angular, web-applications, mean-stack

I'm new to the MEAN stack and I'm following along this online tutorial. In this lesson I should connect the backend with the frontend to register a user, but I keep getting this error in my console:

OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/authentication/register 0 ()

For more detail here is an image of the error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTqQV.png)

Here is my code:

RegisterComponent (Frontend)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        Validators.maxLength(50),
        this.validateEmail
      ])],
      username: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
        Validators.maxLength(15),
        this.validateUsername
      ])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(8),
        Validators.maxLength(35),
        this.validatePassword
      ])],
      confirm: ['', Validators.compose([
        Validators.required
      ])],
    }, {validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'confirm')}
  );
  }

  validateEmail(controls) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
    const regExp = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);

    if (regExp.test(controls.value)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { 'validateEmail': true};
    }
  }

  validateUsername(controls) {
    const regExp = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);

    if (regExp.test(controls.value)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { 'validateUsername': true};
    }
  }

  validatePassword(controls) {
    const regExp = new RegExp(/^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[\d])(?=.*?[\W]).{8,35}$/);

    if (regExp.test(controls.value)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { 'validatePassword': true};
    }
  }

  matchingPasswords(password, confirm) {
    return (group: FormGroup) => {
      if (group.controls[password].value === group.controls[confirm].value) {
        return null;
      } else {
        return {'matchingPasswords': true};
      }
    };
  }

  onRegisterSubmit() {
    const user = {
      email: this.form.get('email').value,
      username: this.form.get('username').value,
      password: this.form.get('password').value
    };

    this.authService.registerUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

AuthService (Frontend)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  domain = 'http://localhost:8080';

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  registerUser(user) {
    return this.http.post(this.domain + '/authentication/register', user).map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Authentication.js (Backend)

```
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = (router) => {

    router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
        if(!req.body.email) {
            res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een email opgeven'});
        } else {
            if(!req.body.username) {
                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een gebruikersnaam opgeven'});
            } else {
                if(!req.body.password) {
                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Je moet een paswoord opgeven'});
                }
                else {
                    let user = new User({
                        email: req.body.email.toLowerCase(),
                        username: req.body.username.toLowerCase(),
                        password: req.body.password
                    });
                    user.save((err) => {
                        if(err) {
                            if(err.code === 11000)
                                res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Gebruikersnaam of email bestaat al' });
                            else {
                                if(err.errors) {
                                    if(err.errors.email) {
                                        res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.email.message})
                                    } else {
                                        if(err.errors.username) {
                                            res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.username.message})
                                        } else { 
                                            if(err.errors.password) {
                                                res.json({ succes: false, message: err.errors.password.message})
                                            }                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    res.json({ succes: false, message: 'Kan gebruiker niet registreren, Error: ', err });
                                }
                            }
                            } else {
                            res.json({ succes: true, message: 'Gebruiker geregistreerd'})
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return router;
};
```

Index.js (Backend)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config/database');
const path = require('path');
const authentication = require('./routes/authentication')(router);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(config.uri, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Could NOT connect to database: ', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to database: ' + config.db);
    }
});

app.use(cors({origin: 'http://localhost:4200'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../frontend/dist'));
app.use('/authentication', authentication);

app.get('**', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/../frontend/dist/index.html'));
  });

  app.listen(8080, () => {
      console.log('Listening on port 8080');
  });
```

These were the only files I modified when following the tutorial. I used cors (in index.js) to connect the frontend to the backend, but it doesn't seem to work. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: Is it the backend endpoint actually being executed? You can add some logging in to double check

Comment: I execute the app in the frontend folder w/ ng serve. Just as they do in the tutorial

Comment: No, what I mean is, can your frontend actually connect to the backend succesfully? Does the code in the backend run when you make the HTTP call?

Comment: are you tested you backend with postman ?

Comment: Yes I tested this with postman. The backend works fine.

Comment: @user184994 I'm so new / noob to this stuff. Do you mean I tested my code with postman? Cause I did and it worked.

Comment: Is your backend code also running on same 8080 port ?

Comment: My frontend is running on 4200 and backend is on 8080. But cors (in index.js) should connect the 2, no?